# Entity Data Model with edmmapping, without oracleclient

Tags: c#, oracle, frameworks, entity

I'm using an EDM (entity framework) for oracle without an oracle client on the client.
This works fine with the following:

1) Extra configuration in the app.config

```
  <system.data>
<DbProviderFactories>
  <remove invariant ="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" />
  <add name="Oracle Data Provider for .NET"
  invariant="Oracle.DataAccess.Client"
  description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET"
  type="Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
</DbProviderFactories>
```

2) some dll's in the application root
- msvcr71.dll, orannzsbb11.dll, oci.dll, oraociei11.dll, OraOps11w.dll, Oracle.DataAccess.dll

Now I'm trying to add some custom mapping in my app.config

```
<oracle.dataaccess.client>
<settings>
  <add name="int16" value="edmmapping number(4,0)" />
  <add name="int32" value="edmmapping number(9,0)" />
  <add name="int64" value="edmmapping number(18,0)" />
</settings>
```

This works fine when the oracle client is installed, but when the oracleclient is not available i get the following:
Configuration system failed to initialize
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized configuration section

Somebody knows how to solve this error when there is no oracleclient installed ?